# Angular Dev Tools state pre-set

Tags: angular, devtools

Is there a way to record the current state of the app with the angular dev tools.
Therefore, it will be possible to start with a particular state snapshot on the next refresh?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by state. You could put data in the local storage and that data would persist across page refreshes. But the whole angular app will reload on refresh.

Comment: At the time of development, I might have some components that become visible only after a few clicks.
For example a tabs that sit in a modal component
I want to save the state that renders the app with the modal opened.
I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to do it with the dev-tools...

Comment: Any data that is not persisted will be lost when angular app refreshes. I'm guessing you are running into this every time you make a change and the app refreshes? Sadly there is no way around it.

Comment: @PreethaPinto the question is if the angular dev tools can take such a snap shot like in this screen shot:
https://angular.io/generated/images/guide/devtools/search.png

and persist for the next reload?

Comment: Short answer is no. It cant.